# <SQLITE> compare old value and new value

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have a trigger.
I want to do insert changed values after every update.
But I get syntax error on line IF .. THEN,  and I can't find example.

```
IF (IFNULL(NEW.symbol,'') <>  IFNULL(OLD.symbol,'')) THEN
INSERT INTO LOG(old_value, new_value, DATA, user)
VALUES ('Symbol: '|| IFNULL(OLD.symbol,''), 'Symbol: ' (IFNULL(NEW.symbol,''),     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, id_user)
```

Can You help me?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no `IF` statement.

You must put the condition into the [`WHEN` clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) of the trigger.

Comment: WHEN or WHERE clause?
Can you show a little sample how to do it?